# treeview treenodes copying

Tags: c#

I have many nodes in the treeview like nodes it children, children of children....

i wanted to copy those entire content and paste it in another node. 
I dont want to use clone method since it affects object of original node from which it s copied.

Comment: The main idea of clone method is to create a copy of object and nothing else, what do you mean affect original node?

Comment: tat means... i m adding a node'a' which is populated to treeview by cloning the node'a'. later if i add somecontent to node'a' the treeview is flickering

Comment: So you problem is flickering? The other behavior you describe does not do that. A clone wont affect the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using recursive like this

```
private void IterateTreeNodes( TreeNode originalNode, TreeNode rootNode )
{
  foreach ( TreeNode childNode in originalNode.Nodes )
  {
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode( childNode.Text );
    newNode.Tag = childNode.Tag;
    treeView2.SelectedNode = rootNode;
    treeView2.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add( newNode );
    IterateTreeNodes( childNode, newNode );
  }
}

// copy nodes from treeView1 to treeView2
private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  foreach ( TreeNode originalNode in treeView1.Nodes )
  {
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode( originalNode.Text );
    newNode.Tag = originalNode.Tag;
    treeView2.Nodes.Add( newNode );
    IterateTreeNodes( originalNode, newNode );
  }
}
```

it's a code snippet from http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-clone-or-copy-all-the-nodes-from-one-treeview-control-to-another.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the traversal algorithm

at each step, you can you can put the traversed node to an object and put that object in an objectList...

All the best...